# ggpubr ,ggpp, ggformula functions not working with ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly, ggpubr, ggformula

I am using a few functions from ggpubr and ggpp to draw my plots.
Specifically, i am using the functions: `geom_quadrant_lines()`, `stat_quadrant_lines()`, `geom_lm`, `stat_regline_equation` in my plot.
However, when i convert my ggplot2 object into a plotly object using `ggplotly()`, the above dont seem to be working.
Is there any workaround? Adding the geoms to the plotly object also dont seem to work

Example Code and Errors Below:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(ggpubr)
library(ggpp)
library(ggformula)

set.seed(1234)
data <- data.frame(x = -5:4 + runif(10,-1,1), y = seq(-15,12,3)-runif(10,-1,1)*2)
head(data)

g <- ggplot(data = data, aes(x=x, y=y)) +geom_point() +
  stat_mean(color = "blue") +
  geom_quadrant_lines()+
  stat_quadrant_counts()+

  stat_regline_equation( formula   = y~x, aes(label =  paste( ..eq.label.., ..adj.rr.label.., sep="~~")),output.type="expression", label.y.npc = 0.8, label.x.npc = 0.0, colour="black", size = 2.5) +
  labs(title= "Example Plot") + #change the number of days here
  geom_lm(interval = "prediction", level = 0.95) 
g

p <- ggplotly(g)
p

p %>% geom_lm(mapping = aes(x=x, y=y), data = data, interval = "prediction", level = 0.95)
```

The ggplot2 output is
[image: ggplot2 output]

Once converted into plotly object using ggplotly, it becomes
[image: ggplotly object]

I also get the below warning messages

```
> p <- ggplotly(g)
Warning messages:
1: In geom2trace.default(dots[[1L]][[1L]], dots[[2L]][[1L]], dots[[3L]][[1L]]) :
  geom_GeomQuadrantLines() has yet to be implemented in plotly.
  If you'd like to see this geom implemented,
  Please open an issue with your example code at
  https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues
2: In geom2trace.default(dots[[1L]][[1L]], dots[[2L]][[1L]], dots[[3L]][[1L]]) :
  geom_GeomTextNpc() has yet to be implemented in plotly.
  If you'd like to see this geom implemented,
  Please open an issue with your example code at
  https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues
3: In geom2trace.default(dots[[1L]][[1L]], dots[[2L]][[1L]], dots[[3L]][[1L]]) :
  geom_GeomLm() has yet to be implemented in plotly.
  If you'd like to see this geom implemented,
  Please open an issue with your example code at
  https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues
```

Comment: `geom_lm` doesn't seem to come from `ggpubr` or `ggpp` as far as I can tell. Should we be loading another library?

Comment: My bad. ggformula package has the function geom_lm. Thanks for spotting